I'm having problems when checking the middleware to see if the user has a signature on the stripe
When I try to put the code in the middleware this error occurred
Error message : " TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring') "
Apparently whenever I use getUserStripeCustomerId and getUserStripeCustomerId this error happens.
Here is my middleware
import micromatch from 'micromatch';
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

import { getCurrentUser } from 'models/user';  
import { getUserStripeCustomerId } from '@/lib/stripe';  
import { getByCustomerId } from 'models/subscription'; 

import env from './lib/env';

// Add routes that don't require authentication
const unAuthenticatedRoutes = [
  '/api/hello',
  '/api/health',
  '/api/auth/**',
  '/api/oauth/**',
  '/api/scim/v2.0/**',
  '/api/invitations/*',
  '/api/webhooks/stripe',
  '/api/webhooks/dsync',
  '/auth/**',
  '/invitations/*',
  '/terms-condition',
  '/unlock-account',
  '/login/saml',
  '/.well-known/*',
];

export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const { pathname } = req.nextUrl;

  
// Bypass routes that don't require authentication
  if (micromatch.isMatch(pathname, unAuthenticatedRoutes)) {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  const redirectUrl = new URL('/auth/login', req.url);
  redirectUrl.searchParams.set('callbackUrl', encodeURI(req.url));

  let user; 
  
// JWT strategy
  if (env.nextAuth.sessionStrategy === 'jwt') {
    const token = await getToken({
      req,
    });

    if (!token) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(redirectUrl);
    }
    user = token.user;
  }

  
// Database strategy
  else if (env.nextAuth.sessionStrategy === 'database') {
    const url = new URL('/api/auth/session', req.url);

    const response = await fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        cookie: req.headers.get('cookie') || '',
      },
    });

    const session = await response.json();

    if (!session.user) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(redirectUrl);
    }
    user = session.user;
  }

  if (user) {  
    const customerId = await getUserStripeCustomerId(user);  
    const subscriptions = await getByCustomerId(customerId);  
  
    const hasActiveSubscription = subscriptions.some(subscription => subscription.active);  
  
    if (!hasActiveSubscription) {  
      const noSubscriptionUrl = new URL('/no-subscription', req.url); 
// Update this URL as necessary  
      return NextResponse.redirect(noSubscriptionUrl);  
    }  
  }  
  

  
// All good, let the request through
  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico|api/auth/session).*)'],
};


can you share the full error trace?
